# Need to host a website with an integrated payment gateway?

Tags: web-hosting, ecommerce

Please advise me how to host a website which includes a payment gateway in India.

I would like to host an e-commerce web application for my own business.  It would need to be used by all type of people.

Answer (score 1):

You could always integrate [Google-Checkout](https://checkout.google.com/seller/integrate.html) or [PayPal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_overview) into your systems using PHP, Java, or .Net. These two are used all of over the web.